# JAVA HttpURLConnection connexion + proxy

Tags: java

I am trying to do a GET request in Java using HttpURLConnection. Everytime I do this however, I get a 400: Bad Request each time. What do I need to change to make it work?

WHen i'm using it on a computer behind a proxy I have an error.
And also when I use Curl with PHP and this proxy, it's workink without password or authentification, so i think the problem is not there.

If someone know why ?

thank you

the error:

```
url connect ...
ERROR = 400
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection:http://google.com
Bad request
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@133796
```

and here is my code:

```
package test;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Connect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpURLConnection connexion = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://google.com");

            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "IP_PROXY");
            System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");

            System.out.println("url connect...");
            connexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connexion.setRequestMethod("GET");


            InputStream is;

            if (connexion.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
                System.out.println("Erreur = " + connexion.getResponseCode());
                System.out.println(connexion.toString());
                System.out.println(connexion.getResponseMessage());
                System.out.println(connexion.getErrorStream());

            } else if (connexion.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                System.out.println(connexion.getResponseMessage());
            } else {
                System.out.println(is = connexion.getInputStream());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            connexion.disconnect();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

URL offers you a method to set the Proxy.

`url.openConnection(new Proxy(...));`

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer

On this code I use the System properties setter : System.setProperty
But just before I was doing on this way:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("IP_PROXY", 80));
connexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
```

But same result, and im sure the port is 80, not 8080